# Android: How can I store custom objects inside ArrayList in strings.xml

Tags: java, android, xml

So I want to create an ArrayList of custom objects or custom object properties inside the strings.xml file. I want to store them there because I need them as resources for my app. Also is that a good idea? If I store let's say approx 1000 items inside that ArrayList. Would that make my application a lot more slower? If yes, what is the best way to store them? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do not store them in the Strings.xml, use a separate resources file instead !!!

Comment: Would be simpler to store and xml or json file in assets folder an load it at startup

Answer (score 0):

1 seems to be simple types

2 then serialize

3 store in file (binary, no xml)

4 read the file

5 deserialize